# Simplification of ArcTan

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica provides the following function to compute the arctangent of a number, preserving quadrant information:

```
ArcTan[x,y]
```

for real $x$ and $y$, when $y = 0$ and $x \ne 0$, $\arctan(y/x) = 0$. However, Mathematica doesn't perform this simplification:

```
FullSimplify[ArcTan[x,0], Assumptions->{x \[Element] Reals}]
(* ArcTan[x, 0] *)
```

Is this an error on my part or is there an underlying reason why this simplification isn't performed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because M does not know the actual numerical value of `x` (or rather its sign).

Let say `x` was `1`

```
ArcTan[1,0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what if `x` was `-1` ?

```
ArcTan[-1,0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, a mathematical error on my end then. I suppose I was overthinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Assuming[0 < x < π, Simplify@ArcTan[x, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

ArcTan simplifications are somehow limited:

```
Simplify[ArcTan[x, y], {x == y, 0 < y, 0 < x}]
```

Sadly only gives:

```
ArcTan[y, y]
```